# Expression Syntax in Function Error Help! C/C++

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement, syntax-error

Please help with my switch case I'm not sure on how I'm meant to put my functions in the cases. Do I keep the parameters in?

```
void ChoiceConvert(char unit){      

char c, f;

printf("Enter your choice for converting from Kelvin\n1. 'c' to convert to Celcius\n2. 'f' to convert to Farenheit");

switch(unit)
{
    case 'c':
        ConvertCel(int temp, const int Freeze);
        break;
    case 'f':
        ConvertFar(int temp, const int Freeze);
        break;
    default:
        printf("\n");       
}

return;}
```

This is the error I am getting.

Error E2188 state.cpp 53: Expression syntax in function ChoiceConvert(char)

Error E2188 state.cpp 56: Expression syntax in function ChoiceConvert(char)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but functions expect arguments when called, not parameters :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code.
**First**: this function is meant to convert a temperature- you pass the char unit that you want it converted to- either C or F. SO

```
char c, f;    
printf("Enter your choice for converting from Kelvin\n1. 'c' to convert to 
Celcius\n2. 'f' to convert to Farenheit");
```

shouldn't be inside the function at all - it should be asked previous to the function, and then the answer is passed into `ChoiceConvert`.

**Second**: there's no temperature here. I assume you should ask the user that in `main()` as well, and pass that in as an argument as well as the unit.

**Third**: As stated by others, you're writing the function parameters, not its arguments. You should have the parameters (ie. the function declaration & definition) *outside* of this function, and then you CALL it within this function. [Check this out in order to learn the difference between declarations, definitions, and calling.](http://www.studytonight.com/cpp/functions-in-cpp) It's pretty vital base knowledge for programming.

Here's how I would do it:

```
int main() 
{
    char conversion;
    int temperature;

    printf("Enter your choice for converting from Kelvin\n1. 'c' to convert to Celcius\n2. 'f' to convert to Fahrenheit");
    std::cin >> conversion;  // requires #include <iostream>
    printf("Enter the temperature you wish to convert:");
    std::cin >> temperature; // requires #include <iostream>

    ChoiceConvert(temperature, conversion); // calling the function
}

void ChoiceConvert(double temp, char unit)
{      
    switch(unit)
    {
    case 'c':
        ConvertCel(temp);
        break;
    case 'f':
        ConvertFar(temp);
        break;
    default:
        printf("\n");       
    }
}

void ConvertCel(double temp)
{
    // conversion here
}
void ConvertFar(double temp)
{
    // conversion here
}
```

Also, UI side note- be careful: if you're looking for the user to input characters, making it a numbered list can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling your conversion functions you are using their declaration instead of passing them actual values.

This is one of the offending lines:

```
ConvertFar(int temp, const int Freeze);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ConvertCel(int temp, const int Freeze);
```

You placed function signature instead of a statement. Twice.

Comment: @user7973155: You should pick up your C++ book and re-read it, so as to understand the language's basics. We cannot help you further because you have not explained what you want to do.

Comment: @user7973155 1. It is unclear what is the source of temperature. Is it entered by user inside this procedure? 2. It is unclear when exactly the user inputs the destination scale. Should it be done inside this procedure right after the temp value? 3. `char c, f;` looks a redundant declaration. You're asking the user of what scale should the conversion be performed to yet get this info from the procedure's argument. In other words, you should put it all together and try to plan what should be done at what exact moments. Then maybe you can write the right code.